# Fetch the stored data using Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my code below I can store data using Core Data. The data that I store is reward. How do I fetch that reward data from Core Data? How would I get the total of reward in my Core Data every time there is a reward that has been added to that certain user? I use `loggedInUserHouseNumber` for every user. How do I fetch reward data and reward total equal with that `loggedInUserHouseNumber`? . I want to get all data and total reward equal to that loggedinuserhousenumber  can anyone provide answer?

```
 loggedInUserHouseNumber =  (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "loggedInUserHouseNumber")  as! String)
```

fetch request code

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "GroceryItem")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


self.saveReward(reward: rewardInt)
```

Saving the data code:

```
func saveReward(reward: Int64){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let groceryData = GroceryItem(context: context) // Link GroceryItem & Context
    groceryData.reward = reward
    groceryData.isSelected = false
    groceryData.houseNo = loggedInUserHouseNumber
    //        print("data:", groceryItem.name)
    print("ang reward nga na save: ", groceryData.reward)
    print("jelordrey")
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
}
```

Comment: Did you try with **NSFetchRequest**?

Comment: yeah i did  tried it Sir

Comment: Could you please post your fetch method here?

Comment: i have updated my question above please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **NSPredicate** to make your query for a particular houseNo, you can try with the below sample code.

```
let loggedInUserHouseNumber =  (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "loggedInUserHouseNumber")  as! String)
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "GroceryItem")
//Create query 
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "houseNo = %@", loggedInUserHouseNumber ?? "")
 do {

       if let models = try context.fetch(request) as? [GroceryItem] {
        // You will get count 
        let count = models.count
        var total = 0
         for model in models {
            total = total + model. reward
       }

    }
   } catch let error {
        // Handle error
    }
```

Comment: how about in getting the total of rewards Sir? , for example ive added rewar which is 10 then i added again , how would i get the total?

Comment: at line guard let model ..... ther is an error which is Errors thrown from here are not handled

Comment: Check the updated code  for the error. When you get all records (here models) for that user, now you have to loop and add reward.

Comment: reward is already stored to that user when saveReward . how to get reward total? example i add 10 then i add another reward which is 20 , now how to get its total?

Comment: also error in Use of unresolved identifier 'fetcher'

Comment: i have fixed the error above sir,  now the only thing i want to know is how to get all reward total

Comment: Replace "fetcher" with "request" & loop the models and count total.

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrappin at line 
        let models = try context.fetch(request) as? [GroceryItem]

Comment: it means your request don't have the record. set Debug breakpoint and check in console.

Comment: what you mean what request record that i dont have? i was in break point it was able toget the loggsedhouseno

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>' at line   if let request = request {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168479/discussion-between-razib-mollick-and-durn-kurvirck).